# will you Get it In a Blue moon?

Tags: riddle

## Riddle: will you Get it In a Blue moon?

**Who am I?**

> I am not valid in any language but can be found in the dictionary.
>   You can't say me and you can't understand me.
>   A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start.
>
> I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH.
>   It is me if you try to write `riddle` and really write `drdlei`.
>   I am in this post.

So I am asking you: *Who am I?*

Okay, I am giving you a hint:

**Hint 1:**

> If your reputation is a bug, you can remove me from posts, here at SE.

And I give you an other hint, I already  gave in the comments:

**Hint 2:** (I changed something)

> The title is a **BIG** hint *to start with*.

Comment: Is it something to do with Spoonerism?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay It is the right direction, but it is not Spoonerism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you...

> gibberish?

"I am not valid in any language but can be found in the dictionary."

> *noun*, unintelligible or meaningless speech or writing; nonsense.

"You can't say me and you can't understand me."

> Written gibberish is likely unpronounceable and spoken gibberish is not understandable.

"A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start."

> Because a doctor's handwriting is often messy and unintelligible?

"I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH."

> These are often used as meaningless text gibberish (such as for a string value in a programming example) since they just represent pressing sequential keys from left to right on a row of a QWERTY keyboard. [As Chris points out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58686/will-you-get-it-in-a-blue-moon#comment179977_58707), QWERTY isn't *technically* gibberish, since [it has a meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qwerty).

"It is me if you try to write `riddle` and really write `drdlei`."

> A sample of gibberish.

"I am in this post."

> Yes. ;)

**Hint 1:**

> If you're bothered by your low rep, you can edit the gibberish out of questions to earn some.

**Hint 2:**

> The only capital letters in the title are "GIB", the start to the word.

Comment: Good answer, but "you can't say me" doesn't seem to fit at all, at least not the way you have described your answer.

Comment: Hey, this is the correct answer. Although I thought something different with `A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start.`: The word doctor is a title and there was a hint in the title, and with hint1 I thought of the millenium (Y2K) bug, and the editing privilege starts at 2K rep here at puzzling.SE

Comment: QWERTY isn't really gibberish. It is a perfectly valid word in common usage (cf https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qwerty ) so I'm not sure that line works (though it may be what the OP had in mind)

Comment: @Chris, oh, didn't knew that ...

Answer (score 4):

You might be ...

> [image]

```
I am not valid in any language but can be found in the dictionary.
```

> The **up-arrow** or **shift** symbol is not a word in any language, but shifted (capitalized) letters are found in dictionaries, as is the word "shift".

```
You can't say me and you can't understand me.
```

> The symbol is not something you can pronounce, nor get any real meaning from when it's all by itself.

```
A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start.
```

> The title "Doctor" (or "M.D.") needs a shift key to type.

```
I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH.
```

> Yup, those are **shifted** (capitalized) letters.

```
It is me if you try to write riddle and really write drdlei.
```

> Yup, those letters have **shifted** around.

```
I am in this post.
```

> Yup.

Hint 1:

> `If your reputation is a bug, you can remove me from posts, here at SE.`
>  You can remove the **up-arrow** (up-votes) on posts.

Hint 2:

> `The title is a BIG hint to start with.`
>  BIG letters at the starts of some of the words in the title, suggest **shifted** (capitalized) letters.

Comment: Good idea, too, but not correct

Comment: That 'doctor explanation' was really forced...

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> nonce?

---

I am not valid in any language [...]

> Nonces are not part of a standard language by definition

[...] but can be found in the dictionary.

> The word *nonce* is in the dictionary. Or it could be a reference to nonces that become full-fledged words.

You can't say me and you can't understand me.

> Nonces often don't have an identifiable meaning. Written nonces often don't have an obvious pronunciation.

A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start.

> ??

I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH.

> Examples of nonces.

It is me if you try to write riddle and really write drdlei.

> drdlei is a nonce

I am in this post.

> drdlei and ASDFGH

Comment: Very close, but not the solution.

Comment: I added a hint.

Comment: Pity, that sounded good, especially, because (n)once in a blue moon could have been the meaning of the title.

Comment: Yes, that would have been a good idea, too, but look at the title, maybe I hid an other message in it ...

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> Colon (:)

Reasoning:

*I am not valid in any language but can be found in the dictionary.*

> The colon isn't in any word in the dictionary, but the word "colon" is in the dictionary.

*You can't say me and you can't understand me.*

> The colon symbol itself isn't pronouncable? Admittedly, this one's a bit of a stretch.

*A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start.*

> A doctor might not be able to help you with this puzzle, but they can definitely help you if you're having problems with your colon (body part).

*I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH.*

> No idea.

*It is me if you try to write `riddle` and really write `drdlei`.*

> Super stretching on this one, but colons usually precede lists in text. Lists can be ordered or unordered, like the words riddle and drdlei.

*I am in this post.*

> *So I am asking you(:) Who am I?*

Comment: Good idea, but not the solution (wrong direction)

Comment: I added a hint.

Answer (score 2):

My Guess is

> "Typo" ? Related with Keyboard and to write riddle and really write drdlei is a typo.

Comment: This could fit, too, but is nor the original answer

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> Anagrams

---

---

`I am not valid in any language but can be found in the dictionary`:

> Most anagrams are not valid words, but the word "anagram" itself is in the dictionary.

`You can't say me and you can't understand me`:

> Anagrams are really hard to pronounce and understand. Try pronouncing "aaarngm".

`A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start`:

> Error 404: explanation not found

`I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH`:

> "QWERTY" and "ASDFGH" could be anagrams of some word. (I tried solving them but couldn't so this line may just be stating that anagrams are weird looking words)

`It is me if you try to write riddle and really write drdlei`

> Dah! "drdlei" is an anagram of "riddle".

`I am in this post`:

> There are two:
> **1.** In the title, the uppercased letters are "GIB", which is an anagram of "BIG".
> **2.** There is an anagram of "riddle".

Hint 1:

> 404

Hint 2:

> In the title, the uppercased letters are "GIB", which is an anagram of "BIG". (lazily copy-pasted)

Comment: That is a great idea, too, but not the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> an initialism?

I am not valid in any language but can be found in the dictionary.

> Initialisms aren't words in any language but some initialisms are defined in the dictionary

You can't say me and you can't understand me.

> Initialisms aren't pronounced as words but as each letter in turn. Nor do they have meaning as a word.

A doctor cannot help you but doctor is something that should give you a start.

> 'Doctor'-> 'M.D' = initialism

I can be QWERTY and ASDFGH.

> Hmm. These can be initialisms? QWERTY is sort of an acronym

It is me if you try to write riddle and really write drdlei.

> As could be this

I am in this post.

> See above

**Hint 1:**

> Presumably you can replace these with what they stand for to clarify posts if your rep is 2,000+ (year of the millennium *bug*)

Comment: Hey, this is a great solution. You also found some solutions, the accepted one did not found, ...

Answer (score 1):

Closely related to @Vikalp's answer, but I think it's

> misprint

Comment: This could fit, too, but is nor the original answer